# Is it allowed to carry 24" LED Monitor inside checkin luggage to Australia?

Tags: luggage, airport-security, check-in, prohibited-items, fragile-luggage

I'm planning wrap my 24" computer monitor with clothes and pack it inside my checkin luggage. Will this be allowed with airport security?

I even have a rigifoam box which I can use to put the monitor and then wrap it with the clothes. But will this cause any security issues in Australian airports?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any policies banning computer monitors in checked luggage; restrictions around electronics are usually related to high-capacity lithium batteries and a monitor wouldn't contain one of those.

To be certain, you should check your airline's website for details of what's (not) allowed.